# How to use NSTask in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, terminal, nstask

I am having a bit of trouble with `NSTask()` in Swift (for an OS X application). Can someone post a  snippet of code in Swift that uses `NSTask()` correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a task…

```
let task = NSTask()
```

Select a path…

```
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/say"
```

Pass any arguments to the command…

```
task.arguments = ["I'm Guybrush Threepwood, Mighty Pirate!"]
```

Launch the task, and block the current thread until it's done…

```
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

Comment: do you have to have terminal open?

Comment: No, you don't. Just copy and paste that code onto Playground and check the result.